# Como alterar a propriedade datatable de uma tabela criada

Tags: jquery-datatables

Quero alterar a propriedade *"serverSide"* para **false** se a condição for satisfeita, como alterar isso de uma tabela criada com Datatable?

```
    var tabela = $("#lista-dados").DataTable({
      "processing": false,
      "serverSide": true,
      "autoWidth": true,
      "ajax": {
        "type": "POST",
        "data": ws_datatable,
        "url": "./functions/ws_datatable.php"
      },
      "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500, -1]],
      "pageLength": 10,
      "bStateSave": true,
      "paging": true,                                    
      "dom": "lBfrtipr",

   });
```

Seria algo assim que eu queria

```
if (x == 2) {
 "serverSide": false,
}
```

Comment: Você já tentou usar o if dentro da propriedade? exemplo: `"serverSide": if(x == 2){ 
false }else{ true }`

Comment: Não dá certo, essa alteração de propriedade deve ser feita após um evento de clique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O DataTables tem uma série de configurações que apenas podem ser definidas no momento da inicialização não depois.

Ver https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3 para mais detalhes

**Solução proposta**

Para alterar essa opção destrói a DataTable e reconstrói

Inicialização

```
 var tabela = $("#lista-dados").DataTable({
      "processing": false,
      "serverSide": true,
      "autoWidth": true,
      "ajax": {
        "type": "POST",
        "data": ws_datatable,
        "url": "./functions/ws_datatable.php"
      },
      "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500, -1]],
      "pageLength": 10,
      "bStateSave": true,
      "paging": true,                                    
      "dom": "lBfrtipr",

   });
```

Alteração

```
if (x == 2) {



 if ( $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#lista-dados' ) ) {

      table = $('#example').DataTable();
      table.destroy();


     var tabela = $("#lista-dados").DataTable({
          "processing": false,
          "serverSide": false, 
          "autoWidth": true,
          "ajax": {
            "type": "POST",
            "data": ws_datatable,
            "url": "./functions/ws_datatable.php"
          },
          "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500, -1]],
          "pageLength": 10,
          "bStateSave": true,
          "paging": true,                                    
          "dom": "lBfrtipr",

       });


}


}
```